# How can I change Ionic on-hold Gesture duration?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic on-hold Gesture has a default timeout duration of 500ms as stated [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/). I need to trigger some callback after a custom duration other than this predefined value. I found this [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/set-timeout-for-gesture-hold-event/2979) relevant for which the callback within $timeout still fires up after 500ms.

Could anyone please suggest me the proper approach on this?

Comment: have you used scroll="false" , gesture dont work with it

Comment: yes, I have scrolling disabled on my page. I find that some gestures such as swipe, drag might not work with scroll="false" on some specific devices. For reference please visit [link1](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2115), [link2](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2373). In my case on-hold gesture is working perfectly but the problem is I can't change default timeout of 500ms